# Set & Get session variable value

Tags: session-variables, laravel-8

I am setting session variable in function of a controller like below.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        session(['user_name' => $user_name]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to access that session variable in another function of another controller.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        dd(session('user_name'));   // I am not getting value here
    } 
}
```

I am not getting value from Session Variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        session()->put('user_name', $user_name);
    }
}
```

And you can get it another controller or anywhere like this

`session()->get('user_name');`

Hope this will help you, thanks..

Comment: @abu abu If this answer is helpful then please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark.